# Open link in browser from code behind of installed application C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a winform application. When I run the app in visual studio, following code works to open a link from `DataGridView` link column.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe",
grdRelLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

But when I install the build and try to do the same thing, nothing happens. Is there any other setting that I need to make.

Please help.

Comment: Does it know where to find `chrome.exe` once its installed? and does your app have the required permissions to launch the `chrome.exe`?

Comment: You can pass the link address to `System.Diagnostincs.Process.Start` to open the address using default browser.

Comment: @SamerTufail : Well, I am new to winforms and I dont know what you suggesting. Can you please elaborate.?

Comment: @user2998990 chrome.exe resides in a particular location right locally? like this could be `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:/mybrowser/chrome.exe",
grdRelLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());` ? you need to provide the correct path to where `chrome.exe` is.

Comment: Ok will try this and update you.

Comment: @SamerTufail : I tried that also also, getting complete path from registry and passing it as a parameter. Still no luck.

Comment: @user2998990 u tried my suggestion ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to open link link from your `DataGridView`, you should actually pass url not web browser, ie.:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(grdRelLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

It will end up trying to open given url with default browser for OS.
Ofc make sure that link of url from url is properly formatted.

If `chrome.exe` doesn't work for launching, maybe try shortened one: `chrome`?
Can you also confirm that `Win+R` (a.k.a. `Run...`) and then `chrome.exe` actually opens up **Chrome**?
If not, can you check if 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\` contains `chrome.exe` entry?

If so, maybe url formatting is wrong?

Comment: But I dont know which link is this. grdRelLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() this line give me the url

Comment: It's worth to ensure that links start with `http` or `https`. Other way, it will fail.

Comment: This is what I did in the first place. But it did not work, When I use vs , it works but when installed it doe not work.

Comment: well he mentioned he wanted it to run chrome. Perhaps it should have been made clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a URL in browser with the following snippets:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "http://google.com";
process.Start();
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

In your example, to allow users to launch it from the DataGridView, you should simply define a click event like this:

```
private void grdRelLinks_CellContentClick(object pSender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs pArgs)
{
    if (pArgs.RowIndex > -1 && pArgs.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        string url = grdRelLinks.Rows[pArgs.RowIndex].Cells[pArgs.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2998990 What happens if you place the url in the windows run function (Windows + R) ? Does this launch the application for you?

Comment: I did a quick google to see what could be the cause of your problem and stumbled upon the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10504367/4579864

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    private void OnGridViewContentClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string chromeExePath = CheckIfChromeIsInstalled();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chromeExePath))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yayy Chrome.exe was found !");
            //Path is not null:
            Process.Start(chromeExePath, "http://www.google.de");//Here you can also enter the URL you get from your GridView
            string url = grdRelLinks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            if(!url.StartsWith("http")
            {
               url = $"http://{url}";
            }
            Process.Start(chromeExePath, url);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Chrome.exe not found");
        }
    }

    private string CheckIfChromeIsInstalled()
    {
        DirectoryInfo programFiles = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES"));//Find your Programs folder
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = programFiles.GetDirectories();
        List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
        Parallel.ForEach(dirs, (dir) =>
        {
            files.AddRange(dir.GetFiles("chrome.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)); //Search for Chrome.exe
        });
        //files should only contain 1 entry
        //Return path of chrom.exe or null
        return (files.Count > 0) ? files[0].FullName : null;
    }
```

**NOTE:** Starting this in an extra Thread could be useful !

**EDIT :**
Can you please check if `cmd.exe` works with start `chrome.exe "your URL"` ?!