# Process.Start for ftp:// prompts for app

Tags: c#, ftp, process.start

I'm writing code that will start a download from our company's ftp (`ftp://...`) but when using `Process.Start("ftp://...");` Windows will prompt me for an app to open it with (I'm using Windows 10). If I use `Process.Start("http://www.google.com");` it doesn't prompt. How do I avoid this prompt and just navigate the user to the ftp URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows knows what to do with a URL that starts with `http`: open the default web browser and browse to that URL.  However, it *doesn't* natively know what to do with a URL that starts with `ftp`.

When you're using `Process.Start`, think of it like running a command from the "run" line in Windows.  You usually need to specify an executable to run, and any additional information -- i.e. arguments to the executable -- occur *after* the path or executable name.

In this case, I'd say you just want to start Internet Explorer and provide it your URL as an argument:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"), url);
var proc = Process.Start(psi);
```

**EDIT:** to answer your question about using the default browser, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10504367/2704659) about how to get the default browser's path:

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is it possible to use the default browser to open the ftp url? Or do I have to pick one?

Comment: For future reference, I had to also reference this answer to get a working final product: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17599201/2246411